# Google Cloud Storage + Python : Any way to list obj in certain folder in GCS?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I'm going to write a Python program to check if a file is in certain folder of my Google Cloud Storage, the basic idea is to get the `list` of all objects in a folder, a file name `list`, then check if the file `abc.txt` is in the file name `list`.

Now the problem is, it looks Google only provide the one way to get `obj` `list`, which is `uri.get_bucket()`, see below code which is from https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary#listing-objects

```
uri = boto.storage_uri(DOGS_BUCKET, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
for obj in uri.get_bucket():
    print '%s://%s/%s' % (uri.scheme, uri.bucket_name, obj.name)
    print '  "%s"' % obj.get_contents_as_string()
```

The defect of `uri.get_bucket()` is, it looks it is getting all of the object first, this is what I don't want, I just need get the `obj` name `list` of particular folder(e.g `gs//mybucket/abc/myfolder`) , which should be much quickly.

Could someone help answer? Appreciate every answer!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Update**: the below is true for the older "Google API Client Libraries" for Python, but if you're not using that client, prefer the newer "Google Cloud Client Library" for Python ( https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html ). For the newer library, the equivalent to the below code is:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('bucketname', prefix='abc/myfolder'):
  print(str(blob))
```

Answer for older client follows.

You may find it easier to work with the JSON API, which has a full-featured Python client. It has a function for listing objects that takes a prefix parameter, which you could use to check for a certain directory and its children in this manner:

```
from apiclient import discovery

# Auth goes here if necessary. Create authorized http object...
client = discovery.build('storage', 'v1') # add http=whatever param if auth
request = client.objects().list(
    bucket="mybucket",
    prefix="abc/myfolder")
while request is not None:
  response = request.execute()
  print json.dumps(response, indent=2)
  request = request.list_next(request, response)
```

Fuller documentation of the list call is here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

And the Google Python API client is documented here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Comment: Could you advise how to define client? I already import json and apiclient, but it will throw **NameError: name 'client' is not defined**, I checked the doc and did not found this part of code, thank you!

Comment: Added a bit above with example syntax.

Comment: is there anyway to speed this up? It slow for millions of blobs

Comment: This did not work for me. `str(blob)` shows me `'<Blob: the_bucket_name, the_blob_name, 123456789>'`. Instead, I used `blob.name`.

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
client = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'DEMO_BUCKET'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

The list_blobs() method will return an iterator used to find blobs in the bucket.
Now you can iterate over blobs and access every object in the bucket. In this example I just print out the name of the object.

This documentation helped me alot:

- https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html
- https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/client.html#Client.bucket

I hope I could help!

Comment: And if you want to filter files in particular folder use `bucket.list_blobs(prefix="path")`

Comment: Works great for older versions of the google api. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to look at [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) and [documentation](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/storage-api.html#gcloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys).

```
from gcloud import storage
connection = storage.get_connection(project_name, email, private_key_path)
bucket = connection.get_bucket('my-bucket')

for key in bucket:
  if key.name == 'abc.txt':
    print 'Found it!'
    break
```

However, you might be better off just checking if the file exists:

```
if 'abc.txt' in bucket:
  print 'Found it!'
```

Comment: I'm working on Windows 7, I failed to easy_install gcloud, finally it would end with **warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**, could you advise? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have PyCrypto and all those installed? Windows installers for those are available online I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Install python package google-cloud-storage by pip or pycharm and use below code

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME, prefix=FOLDER_NAME):
  print(str(blob))
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled over this because I was looking for the exact same answer. Answers from Brandon Yarbrough and Abhijit worked for me, but I wanted to get into more detail.

When you run this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = list(storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=PREFIX, fields="items(name)"))
```

You will get Blob objects, with just the name field of all files in the given bucket, like this:

```
[<Blob: BUCKET_NAME, PREFIX, None>, 
 <Blob: xml-BUCKET_NAME, [PREFIX]claim_757325.json, None>, 
 <Blob: xml-BUCKET_NAME, [PREFIX]claim_757390.json, None>,
 ...]
```

If you are like me and you want to 1) filter out the first item in the list because it does NOT represent a file - its just the prefix, 2) just get the name string value, and 3) remove the PREFIX from the file name, you can do something like this:

```
blob_names = [blob_name.name[len(PREFIX):] for blob_name in blobs if blob_name.name != folder_name]
```

Complete code to get just the string files names from a storage bucket:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = list(storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=PREFIX, fields="items(name)"))
blob_names = [blob_name.name[len(PREFIX):] for blob_name in blobs if blob_name.name != folder_name]
print(f"blob_names = {blob_names}")
```

Comment: Note that a subfolder is only returned if you've explicitly created it. If you simply write a file to some path like `path/to/file.json`, then `list_blobs()` won't return `path/to` or `path` unless you've explicitly *created* those objects beforehand.