# Read files from Cloud Storage having definite prefix but random postfix

Tags: python-3.x, file, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am using the following code to read the contents of a file in Google Cloud Storage from Cloud Functions. Here the name of file (filename) is defined. I now have files that will have a definite prefix but the postfix can be anything. 
Example - ABC-khasvbdjfy7i76.csv

How to read the contents of such files?

I know there will be "ABC" as a prefix. But the postfix can be anything random.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob(filename)
contents = blob.download_as_string()
print("Contents : ")
print(contents)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `prefix` parameter of `list_blobs` method to filter objects beginning with your prefix, and iterate on the objects :

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test-bucket')

blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="ABC")

for blob in blobs:
    contents = blob.download_as_string()
    print("Contents of %s:" % blob.name)
    print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the entire path of a file to be able to read it. And since the client can't guess the random suffix, you will first have to list all the files with the non-random prefix.

There is a `list` operation, to which you can pass a prefix, as shown here: [Google Cloud Storage + Python : Any way to list obj in certain folder in GCS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398898/google-cloud-storage-python-any-way-to-list-obj-in-certain-folder-in-gcs)