# What's the best way to check if a file exists in a GCS bucket in Python, searching for a partial file name?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to do frequent checks to see if a daily set of files is in a GCS bucket. The files are generated in the format `Context_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt.gz` and I'd like to be able to check based on the context and the date portion of the timestamp (eg Sales_20190908*.txt.gz).

What's the best way to go about this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting up [Cloud Pub/Sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) for the bucket. Your application can receive a push notification every time a new object is uploaded to the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398898/google-cloud-storage-python-any-way-to-list-obj-in-certain-folder-in-gcs) should help you with pulling file names from a GCS Bucket.
[This site](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) may also help.

You can get date and time from `datetime` and turn that into a string.

```
import datetime
def date_to_string():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_string = ""
    date_string += "{:04d}".format(now.year)
    date_string += "{:02d}".format(now.month)
    date_string += "{:02d}".format(now.day)
    date_string += "{:02d}".format(now.hour)
    date_string += "{:02d}".format(now.minute)
    date_string += "{:02d}".format(now.second)
    return date_string
```

And then you can simply check if the filename is in the list of blobs:

```
if "Context_"+date_string+".txt.gz" in blob_list:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do frequent checks I would suggest you [creating](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#creating_jobs) a Cron Job with Cloud Scheduler that triggers a Cloud Function with an HTTP request. Then you will [create a function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) triggered by an HTTP request which will list the [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) of the bucket and filter them by name.

Also [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) you may find more details about object listing.