# Read and write images from GCS via python (Flask)

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

In local machine, I am able to extract the feature of images and store the corresponding .npy file in a different folder.

```html
from PIL import Image
from feature_extractor import FeatureExtractor
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fe = FeatureExtractor()

    for img_path in sorted(Path("./static/img").glob("*.jpg")):
        print(img_path)  # e.g., ./static/img/xxx.jpg
        feature = fe.extract(img=Image.open(img_path))
        feature_path = Path("./static/feature") / (img_path.stem + ".npy")  # e.g., ./static/feature/xyz.npy
        np.save(feature_path, feature)
```

Now I want to host this in google cloud. But for this I need to read and write the images from Google Cloud Storage. Is there any library like Path for GCS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is official client lib for this
`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`

See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

---

Edit:
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22399617/7888973

If you want to list flies within a GCS bucket:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('bucketname', prefix='abc/myfolder'):
  print(str(blob))
```

Comment: I tried using this library (google-cloud-storage) but couldn't solve this issue. I was able to connect with GCS but I had to download the image first and then upload the feature array.

Comment: I don't know how exactly FeatureExtractor.extract works but I imagine you need to have the image on your machine in order to compute it. So you have to download it first, then extract and then upload .npy back again.

Comment: If you are asking how to download and upload from GCS using python: Look at official GCS python lib GitHub example usage: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/#example-usage ||| |1. Retrieve an existing bucket (`bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id')`) |2. download orginal file (`blob = bucket.get_blob('remote/path/filename.img')`)
 |3. FeatureExtractor.extract
 |4. upload npy file to GCS
(`new_blob = bucket.blob('remote/path/filename.npy')`
`new_blob.upload_from_filename(filename='/local/path/filename.npy')`)

Comment: Yeah. I am also trying with this method. I am able to read the image and extract the feature too. Right now, I am getting issue in uploading the .npy file in GSC. Let's see.